# Parameterized Connection Manager in SSISDB Job not using the set ODBC password

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent, jobs, odbc

Regardless of the solution I find online I have been unable to get my SSMS Scheduled Job to successfully complete my ODBC-connected SSIS ETL Packages.

I have tried deploying the SSIS project/packages with:

- EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey
- EncrpytAllWithPassword
- DontSaveSensitive

When encrypting with my UserKey, the jobs run when I am logged in as myself in Windows and SSMS and manually trigger the job. The job fails when I am not logged in and the scheduler triggers the job. I have Credentials and a SSIS Proxy set up, and have carefully followed many different step-by-step guides that use this method. It still fails when triggered overnight.

When encrypting with Password, I can't get it to run at all. I can't find any field in SSMS to input the password so the xml package can be decrypted. Our team would prefer to use this method so we can all work on each other's packages should someone be out on vacation or whatever but I've made no headway in getting the Jobs to succeed, the always fail on the ODBC connection.

When not encrypting anything, I have a parameterized ODBC Connection Manager in my SSIS project. I have tried both Environmental Variables as well as just typing the values into the SSISDB Project Configuration window. With this method, I can get individual packages to succeed when I execute them from the SSISDB browser, but when I manually trigger a job that is configured identically to a one-off execution it always fails. I can see the Env variables selected in the job step, but they don't actually get passed into the ODBC ConnectionString property when the job runs.

I'm worried that my Visual Studio is set to override my individual Solution settings and default the deployment to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey, but I haven't been able to find anything in the settings or online to prove that out.